# sh Break CSV files by value of column name matched while retaining header

Tags: awk

I have a directory with many CSV files from table exports

tblA.csv

```
A,B,C
1,1,1
1,2,2
2,2,2
3,3,3
```

tblB.csv

```
C,D,A
1,1,1
1,2,2
2,2,2
3,3,3
```

In order to break the files I found this script

```
   awk -F, '
      NR== 1 { hdr = $0;next}
      {out = "File" $1 ".csv"}
      printed[$1]++<1 {print hdr >out}
      {print $0 > out}
  ' tblA.csv
```

that creates 3 files

```
A,B,C
1,1,1
1,2,2
```

```
A,B,C
2,2,2
```

```
A,B,C
3,3,3
```

Now for tblB.csv I still need to break the file by column A but that column is the 3rd not the 1st

I can't figure out a way to pass the argument A have the it loop the header to find a column name that matches the argument I passed and then break the file using that column value. Or if that column name does not exist just skip the file.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts. Could you please do mention more clearly what is the logic of creating new files?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 csvs basically are used as source for an empty db. After receiving a 10gb file with all users I would prefer to store it on a per user basis, as often I need to reprocess same data when errors happen and it would make it a lot easier to process in parallel after its broken. Each user takes hrs to process

Comment: Are your input files always grouped by the same values in the "A" column as shown in your sample input? If not then please [edit] your question to show disorder in the "A" values as it impacts the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how to print a column by it's name:

**Print a column by it's name:**

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="," }
NR==1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        f[$i] = i
    }
}
{ print $(f["A"]) }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk tblA.csv
A
1
1
2
3
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk tblB.csv
A
1
2
2
3
```

and here's how to use that idiom to do what you asked for robustly and efficiently using any awk* in any shell on every Unix box:

**Split the input file by grouped key values:**

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="," }
NR==1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        f[$i] = i
    }
    hdr = $0
    next
}
!(tgt in f) { exit }
{ curr = $(f[tgt]) }
curr != prev {
    close(out)
    out = "File" curr ".csv"
    print hdr > out
    prev = curr
}
{ print > out }
```

```
$ awk -v tgt='A' -f tst.awk tblA.csv
```

```
$ head File*.csv
==> File1.csv <==
A,B,C
1,1,1
1,2,2

==> File2.csv <==
A,B,C
2,2,2

==> File3.csv <==
A,B,C
3,3,3
```

```
$ awk -v tgt='A' -f tst.awk tblB.csv
```

```
$ head File*.csv
==> File1.csv <==
C,D,A
1,1,1

==> File2.csv <==
C,D,A
1,2,2
2,2,2

==> File3.csv <==
C,D,A
3,3,3
```

The above assumes that the input files are grouped by the key field as shown in your sample input - if they aren't then it can be handled in the awk script:

**Split the input file by non-grouped key values using AWK only:**

```
$ cat tblC.csv
C,D,A
2,2,3
1,2,2
1,1,3
3,3,1
```

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="," }
NR==1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        f[$i] = i
    }
    hdr = $0
    next
}
{ curr = $(f[tgt]) }
curr != prev {
    close(out)
    out = "File" curr ".csv"
    if ( !doneHdr[curr]++ ) {
        print hdr > out
    }
    prev = curr
}
{ print >> out }
```

```
$ awk -v tgt='A' -f tst.awk tblC.csv
```

```
$ head File*.csv
==> File1.csv <==
C,D,A
3,3,1

==> File2.csv <==
C,D,A
1,2,2

==> File3.csv <==
C,D,A
2,2,3
1,1,3
```

but if your files are large it's more efficient to sort them so the key values are grouped before running the awk script so awk doesn't have to repeatedly open/close the output files:

**Split the input file by non-grouped key values using sort+AWK (more efficient for large files):**

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

tgt="$1"
shift

awk -v tgt="$tgt" '
    BEGIN { FS=","; OFS="\t" }
    NR==1 {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            f[$i] = i
        }
    }
    { print (NR>1), $(f[tgt]), NR, $0 }
' "${@:--}" |
sort -k1,1n -k2,2 -k3,3n |
cut -f4- |
awk -v tgt="$tgt" '
    BEGIN { FS="," }
    NR==1 {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            f[$i] = i
        }
        hdr = $0
        next
    }
    { curr = $(f[tgt]) }
    curr != prev {
        close(out)
        out = "File" curr ".csv"
        print hdr > out
        prev = curr
    }
    { print > out }
'
```

```
$ ./tst.sh 'A' tblC.csv
```

```
$ head File*.csv
==> File1.csv <==
C,D,A
3,3,1

==> File2.csv <==
C,D,A
1,2,2

==> File3.csv <==
C,D,A
2,2,3
1,1,3
```

The above works by first using awk to decorate the original input by prepending to each line:

1. `NR>1` = a header-or-not, 0-or-1 indicator so we can ensure the header always still comes first after the `sort`,
2. `$(f[tgt])` = the key value we want to sort on,
3. `NR` = the current line number so we get the same order output as we had input for duplicate keys (can also be done without adding that and then  using GNU sort for `-s`)

then we sort by those fields and then remove them again using `cut` (could do that in the subsequent awk script but `cut` is efficient and avoids cluttering it) before the main awk script starts creating the output files.

**Things to beware of in such AWK scripts:**

* In case you get other answers that do either of the following things, just be aware that:

1. any solution that doesn't `close()` the output files will fail with "too many open files" in most awks once you get past a threshold which may be as low as 15 and even an awk that supports unlimited "open" files such as GNU awk will slow down past that threshold as it has to manage all those "open" files by actually opening/closing them in the OS as needed behind the scenes, and
2. any solution that uses `print > "File" $1 ".csv"` or similar without
   parens around the expression on the right side of the `>` will fail with a syntax error in most awks as that's
   undefined behavior.

Comment: thank you Ed this is a massive help, never used awk before so this syntax baffles me

Answer (score 2):

This is where it's handy to set awk variables on the command line, interspersed with the filenames:

```sh
awk -F, '
    FNR== 1 {hdr = $0; next}
    {out = "File" $col ".csv"}
    printed[$1]++ < 1 {print hdr > out}
    {print > out}
' col=1 tblA.csv col=3 tblB.csv
```

Comment: BUT: since the headers are different, what is FILE1.csv supposed to look like after processing 2 files?

Comment: very true filename needs to be based on the group key and the original file name