# How can I delete all the columns without a certain header inside a folder full of csv files?

Tags: linux, csv, awk, sed

I have a folder with many .csv files in it. I need to remove all the columns that don't have a specific header in those CSV files. In other words, I only need to keep columns with certain headers and delete the rest of the columns in all the CSV files inside that folder.

For example, I only need to keep the columns with the header 'Name', 'Assignment 1', 'Assignment 2', and 'Final grade' in all the CSV files inside the folder.

Wondering how to do this by using Bash regex, awk, sed or any other way?

your help is much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: [edit] your question to show a [mcve] including concise, testable sample input, expected output and your attempt to solve the problem yourself so we can help you (this site exists to help people with their code, not to write code for people). See [ask] if that's not clear. As a start - awk would be the right tool for this and see the first script at the top of https://stackoverflow.com/a/68578793/1745001 for how to refer to a column by it's name.

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you. Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: `csvtool namedcol`

Comment: try using linux file tools such as `cut`. I imagine you can come up with a bash script that will do what you want. I recommend making a backup of your files. Alternatively load files into your spreadsheet software of choice, delete columns as you require, then export again as CSV. Make sure to not interpret the columns in any way and use text only when importing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this, but need to use ' \'  if space present is single column header name

```
csvtool namedcol Name,Assignment\ 1,Assignment\ 2,Final\ grade file.csv
```