# Print columns with a certain header of a CSV file using AWK

Tags: awk

[Current CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huPmv.png)

[Preferred output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esTEU.png)

I was trying to pick specific columns from my CSV file and print it. I wanted to print all the columns which the headers have "Unposted Final Score" string in them.

I could tailor two pieces of code. One piece is giving me all the correct headers but missing the columns' body.
The other piece is giving me only the first full column with the correct header.

I am new to AWK and did my best to tailor something to give me both but I was unsuccessful.

Would any one guide me on this please?

Cheers
B
:)

**Please see my codes here:**

This is the code that gives me only the correct headers and not the body of the columns:

```
{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
    {if ($i ~ /Unposted Final Score/)
    {print $i}
    }
}
```

**output:**

```
A1. Unposted Final Score
A2. Proposal and Storyboard Unposted Final Score
```

=================

This is the code that gives me the first columns and not the rest with the "Unposted Final Score" in them:

```
{ for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) if ($i ~ /Unposted Final Score/) { n=i; break }} { print $n }
```

**output:**

```
A1. Unposted Final Score
56
95
90
93
0
80
61
```

=====================

**My Current CSV file:**

```
ID,Section,A1. Final Score,A1. Unposted Final Score,A2. Current Score,A2. Proposal and Storyboard Unposted Final Score
4836,Sydney A,1,56,,34
5376,Sydney A,2,95,0,1
4760,Sydney A,3,90,,30
4675,Sydney A,4,93,3,0
4873,Sydney B,0,0,33,50
4848,Sydney A,80,80,0,0
4755,Sydney A,61,61,,0
```

**The Preferred CSV file:**

```
A1. Unposted Final Score,A2. Proposal and Storyboard Unposted Final Score
56,34
95,1
90,30
93,0
0,50
80,0
61,0
```

Comment: Hello, welcome on SO. Please learn how to format your questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). As it was, it was impossible to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box the following will robustly, efficiently, and portably print the fields you want in the same order they occur in the input:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR==1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ( $i ~ /Unposted Final Score/ ) {
            out2in[++numOutFlds] = i
        }
    }
}
{
    for (o=1; o<=numOutFlds; o++) {
        i = out2in[o]
        printf "%s%s", $i, (o<numOutFlds ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
A1. Unposted Final Score,A2. Proposal and Storyboard Unposted Final Score
56,34
95,1
90,30
93,0
0,50
80,0
61,0
```

See also [sh Break CSV files by value of column name matched while retaining header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68578179/sh-break-csv-files-by-value-of-column-name-matched-while-retaining-header/68578793#68578793).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in a file called `u.csv`, you could simply try this:

```
cat u.csv | awk -F',' '{printf $4 "," $6 "\n" }'
```

It will give you this output:

```
A1. Unposted Final Score,A2. Proposal and Storyboard Unposted Final Score 
56,34
95,1
90,30
93,0
0,50
80,0
61,0
```

Explanation:

```
awk -F','
```

Will split your lines using `,` as a separator.

I.E., the first line:

```
4836,Sydney A,1,56,,34
```

So, for `awk` the values will be stored in:

```
$1 -> 4836
$2 -> Sydney A
$3 -> 1
$4 -> 54
$5 -> 
$6 -> 34
```

After that, you just use `awk`'s built in `printf` function to make the output what you said you wanted.

Comment: See http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html for why not to do `cat file | awk` and always use `printf "%s", $i` rather than `print $i` for any input data as the latter will fail when the input contains printf formatting chars like `%s`. Don't hard-code a separator char like `","` just set and use OFS, and don't hard-code the character `"\n"` that you hope ORS is set to, just use ORS all as awk is designed to do. So `cat u.csv | awk -F',' '{printf $4 "," $6 "\n" }'` should be `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {print $4, $6}' u.csv`.

Answer (score 0):

The following was tested with GNU `awk` 5.1.0 in POSIX mode and with `awk` 20070501 that comes with macOS. It could be that it doesn't work at all with other versions of `awk`.

Your first attempt is a good starting point. Just do something similar on the first line to record the indexes of the columns to print and then, on all records including the first, print only the corresponding fields:

```sh
$ cat foo.awk
NR==1 {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/Unposted Final Score/) idx[++n]=i}
{for(i=1;i<=n;i++) printf("%s%s", $(idx[i]), (i==n)?ORS:",")}

$ awk -f foo.awk -F, foo.csv
A1. Unposted Final Score,A2. Proposal and Storyboard Unposted Final Score
56,34
95,1
90,30
93,0
0,50
80,0
61,0
```

Explanations:

- We set the input field separator to comma, instead of the default (spaces), with the `-F,` option.
- The `NR==1` condition is true only for the first record (the header). In this block we store all field indexes matching `Unposted Final Score` in the `idx` array. Variable `n` is used to store the number of matching fields, we will use it for the printing of the output. Instead of `idx[++n]=i` we could use `{n=n+1; idx[n]=i}` which is probably easier to understand (the numeric value of a variable is automatically initialized to 0).
- The third block is executed on all lines (no condition). It prints all fields which index is in the `idx` array, followed by a comma, except for the last printed field which is followed by the output record separator (`ORS`, a newline by default).

Comment: That would shuffle the order of the columns for output and could print a newline halfway through the fields that should all be on one line courtesy of `for (i in idx)`, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Scanning-an-Array.

Comment: @EdMorton Right. It works but there is no guarantee and it could as well be by chance. With GNU `awk` this could be controlled with `BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"}`. But I will instead modify my answer for better portability.

Comment: Regarding "it works" - to be clear it's not really that it works, it just happened to produce the expected output for a specific set of input using specific awk versions on specific machines. To me "it works" would mean it would always produce the expected output from any input using any awk and that's not the case.

Comment: This what I mean with _by chance_.

Comment: If you replaced `It works but there is no guarantee and it could as well be by chance` with `it produced the expected output but that's just by chance` it'd be more accurate. Anyway, sounds like we're on the same page.

Comment: Now it's identical to my answer.